# How to find (configure) Qt for cmake project of iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, macos, qt, cmake

I install Qt via online installer on my macOS (Qt for iOS and macOS).
And qmake project works just fine, now I need compile with cmake Qt project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(demo LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)
```

And I can not find Qt.

Direct build configuration:

```
cmake .. -GXcode -DQt5_DIR=/Users/user/Qt/5.14.1/clang_64/lib/cmake/Qt5
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to:
```

Cross-compiling for iOS:

```
cmake .. -GXcode -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=iOS -DQt5_DIR=/Users/user/Qt/5.14.1/ios/lib/cmake/Qt5
...
CMake Error at /Users/user/Qt/5.14.1/ios/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
    qt5core-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Obviously Qt5CoreConfig.cmake is just fine and it is in relatively the same place as for "direct" compilation, but for some reason cmake can not find it

```
$ find /Users/user/Qt/5.14.1/ios/lib/cmake/ -name Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
/Users/user/Qt/5.14.1/ios/lib/cmake//Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can likely solve this by setting your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` CMake variable.

Comment: @squareskittles No, as I show above it works fine for me in "direct compilation case", but relatively the same path doesn't work for cross-compilation case.

Comment: @squareskittles CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't at all work for me. Not for direct, not for cross compilation. While Qt5_Dir works, but only for "direct" case.

Comment: Setting `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/user/Qt/5.14.1/clang_64` should work for "direct" build. If setting `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/user/Qt/5.14.1/ios` doesn't work for cross-compilation, then your toolchain requires external libraries to be under sysroot or some other "root path" specified in the toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

When building for iOS `CMAKE_SYSROOT` is set to `iPhoneOS.sdk` path.

[`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html):

> The CMAKE_SYSROOT variable can also be used to specify exactly one directory to use as a prefix. Setting CMAKE_SYSROOT also has other effects. See the documentation for that variable for more.
>
> These variables are especially useful when cross-compiling to point to the root directory of the target environment and CMake will search there too. By default at first the directories listed in CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH are searched, then the CMAKE_SYSROOT directory is searched, and then the non-rooted directories will be searched.

So, adding the option `-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/Users/user/Qt/5.14.1/ios` will help.